# Normalizing music playlist in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database-normalization

I am trying to practice making good databases because I want to use a MySQL database in my programs. I want to make a program that will help me organize my music collection as a learning experience. According to online sources, I need to "normalize" my database before I start writing the code. However, I am having a lot of trouble trying to "normalize" this data.

I used the pipe | as a field separator, and the comma , as a multiple value separator. This is how I got my data organized so far:

```
Music Artist|Album Title|Media Type|Album Genre|Album Year|Track Playlists|Track Tags|Production Label|Track Number|Track Title|Track Artists

Santana|Shaman|VINYL|Pop|2012|My List, ListyList, Good|GuitarMusic, SampleTag|SBME SPECIAL MKTS|3|Game of Love|Santana, Michelle Branch
Santana|Shaman|VINYL|Pop|2012|My List, ListyList, Another|GuitarMusic, STag|SBME SPECIAL MKTS|4|You Are My Kind|Santana, Seal
Santana|Shaman|VINYL|Pop|2012|My List, ListyList, AList|MyMusic, SpleTag|SBME SPECIAL MKTS|9|Sideways|Santana, Citizen Cope
Santana|Shaman|VINYL|Pop|2012|My List, ListyList, AnotherList|SampTag|SBME SPECIAL MKTS|10|Why Don't You & I|Santana, Chad Kroeger

Mark Ronson|Uptown Special|Digital|Funk|2015|ListyList, Poppy List|Funk, OneHitWonder|Columbia|4|Uptown Funk|Mark Ronson, Bruno Mars

Elijah Thomas|Dark Lord Funk|Digital|Funk|2015|Parodies, Poppy List|Funk, Parody, BetterThanOriginal|K-Face Rules|1|Dark Lord Funk|Elijah Thomas

Soundtrack|Guardians of the Galaxy: Awesome Mix Vol. 1|Digital|Soundtrack|2014|AnotherList|AMix, IamGroot|Hollywood Records|1|Hooked on a Feeling|Blue Swede
Soundtrack|Guardians of the Galaxy: Awesome Mix Vol. 1|Digital|Soundtrack|2014|AnotherList|AwesomeMix, IamGroot|Hollywood Records|3|Spirit in the Sky|Norman Greenbaum
Soundtrack|Guardians of the Galaxy: Awesome Mix Vol. 1|Digital|Soundtrack|2014|AnotherList|AwesomeMix, IamGroot|Hollywood Records|8|Come and Get Your Love|Redbone
Soundtrack|Guardians of the Galaxy: Awesome Mix Vol. 1|Digital|Soundtrack|2014|AnotherList|AMix, IamGroot|Hollywood Records|9|Cherry Bomb|The Runaways
Soundtrack|Guardians of the Galaxy: Awesome Mix Vol. 1|Digital|Soundtrack|2014|AnotherList|AwesomeMix, IamGroot|Hollywood Records|10|Escape (The Piña Colada Song)|Rupert Holmes

Soundtrack|Guardians of the Galaxy: Awesome Mix Vol. 1|Digital|Soundtrack|2014|AnotherList|AwesomeMix|Hollywood Records|11|O-O-H Child|The Five Stairsteps

Pharrel Williams|G I R L|CD|Pop|2014|My List|Happy, Poppy List|Happy, OneHitWonder|Columbia|5|Happy (From "Dispicable Me 2")|Pharrell Williams

Rick Astley|Whenever You Need Somebody|VINYL|Pop|1990|Just In Case|RickRoll, HadToDoIt|RCA|1|Never Gonna Give You Up|Rick Astley
```

And I have:

```
Music Artist(<Artist_ID>, Album Title, Album Genre, Album Year);
Album(<Album_ID>, <Music_ARTIST_ID>, Album Title, Album Genre, Album Year);
```

How can I "Normalize" this data?

Comment: Normalization is a process with many steps and technical notions. You haven't given the relevant info for somene to normalize. (FDs & JDs.) The fact that you haven't given it suggests that you don't even know the basics of normalization. You need to tell us what you did and why, with a reference to what process/notions you are using, so that your question becomes specific, about whether those are in error. Otherwise you are asking for a section/chapter/tutorial/lecture on normalization, which is too broad a question.

Answer (score 1):

Normalization is done on tables of a db to reduce redundancy of data in db & maintain consistency. If you normalize your db, then tables will have:
Music Artist(Artist_ID pk, Album_ID fk); Album(Album_ID pk, Music_ARTIST_ID fk, Album Title, Album Genre, Album Year,Media Type); Tracks(Album_ID fk, Track Playlists,Track Tags,Production Label, Track Number, Track Title,Track Artists);

Comment: @philipxy I've not introduced new columns. Splitted tables only.